# How to add custom mass action with pop up though UI in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I need to add custom mass action , but when you click on mass action option i need one pop up instead of redirecting to action url

that is custom js for my custom mass action

can any one help me on that

is there any option like modifier for mass action also ?

Comment: There are delete option available in ui component in `<massaction name="listing_massaction">` where you can add your custom controller in argument `<item name="url">` Let me know if you need code of that.

Comment: @PrincePatel :- that is normal case adding mass action ? but i dont want like that i need add mass action when u click on that option i need custom pop up or custom block next to action where i need to do further action

Comment: @PradeepKumar did you find the answer?